# SQL - Overview Queries

Tags: c#, sql, rest, api

I've run into a seemingly simple issue when designing a C# -> SQL data access layer.

Here's the pseudocode for what I am trying to do:

```
User.GetOverview()
```

The user overview consists of things like

```
public class UserOverviewModel()
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public SavedSearchModel[] SavedSearches { get; set; }
    public TrackingItemModel[] ItemsToTrack { get; set; }
}
```

So both the **SaveSearchModel** and **TrackingItemModel** are completely different database tables and have a one -> multiple relationship with the user.

My question is, how do you get all this information from a SQL query? At the end of the day, I am trying to return something like this from a REST Api:

```
{
    "Username": "wakawaka54",
    "SavedSearches": [
         { "SearchText" : "40mm" }
         { "SearchText" : "50mm 12v" }
    ],
    "ItemsToTrack": [
         { "ItemID": "1374328575",
           "ItemLink" "www.somelink.com" }
         { "ItemID": "357489574",
           "ItemLink": "www.someotherlink.com" }
    ]
}
```

Should I use a Transaction and return each query separately? Does this cause me to pay the same speed penalty as independent queries?

Answer (score 1):

Use `inner join`

```
SELECT U.UserName, S.SavedSearches, I.ItemsToTrack
FROM tblUsers U INNER JOIN tblSaveSearches S ON U.UserId = S.UserId
INNER JOIN tblItemToTrack I ON U.UserId = I.UserId
```

Then converted return result set to list of `UserOverviewModel` and then serialize it using [NewtonSoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Newtonsoft nuget](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

This is very easy to use.

Comment: Yeah after I get the data. I am asking how do I structure this query, in SQL or C#.

Comment: Do I query each table individually and load each result into arrays, then parse the whole thing as JSON. Or is there some way I can collect all the data I need on one pass to the database?